# How to access JSON array of strings having multiple value and store it in map?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, hashmap, jwt

How to access JSON array of strings having multiple value and store it in map ?

i am trying to fetch the JWT token and want to compare the "aud" claims having multiple values .

```
{
  "iss": "github.io",
  "sub": "taa",
  "aud": [
    "is",
    "kk"
  ],
  "iat": 1646117705,
  "exp": 1646118305
}
```

This is an example JWT token ,

I am storing the values after parsing in **Json::Value payload_root**;
now i want to fetch the "aud" claima from this JSON .

i can directly fetch the value of single claims like
**payload_root[exp]** , but for multiple values how to fetch and store it in a map ?

Comment: You should add what JSON parsing library you are using.

Comment: I am using  #include "json/json.h" (http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/).